# How to check null object in dynamic linq on th fly?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using a dynamic linq on the fly to generate  some request.
 All everything work great except when a class is null. I got `NullException`.
So, I want to do the same things of this:

```
dossiers = dossiers.Where(d => d != null && d.Demandeurs != null && 
           d.Demandeurs.Any(DossierTiers => DossierTiers != null &&
           DossierTiers.Tiers != null && DossierTiers.Tiers.TiersLiesEnfantsActifs != null &&
           DossierTiers.Tiers.TiersLiesEnfantsActifs.Any(TiersLie => TiersLie != null && TiersLie.TiersEnfant != null &&
           TiersLie.TiersEnfant.AdressePrincipale != null && TiersLie.TiersEnfant.AdressePrincipale.Adresse != null &&                
           TiersLie.TiersEnfant.AdressePrincipale.Adresse.CodePostal.StartsWith("45")))).ToList();
```

I don't know how to check `null`.

Comment: You are doing the checks fine you just missed exactly 1. But tbh......I never saw any linq statement so far where so MANY null checks were made. Easy though to overlook one there.

Comment: Actually, this code isn't readable at all. Instead of all those paranoid null checks, I'd suggest you to re-design your model to avoid nulls, and also you need to analyze, why that particular reference is null - maybe, it *must not* be null and bug is elsewhere.

Comment: Yepp that is the most null checks I ever saw. A few unnecessary (like d => d!= null). Also he overlooked one of the checks (CodePostal) which is quite easy to happen with so many checks being made.

Comment: @tonio as its a few general things about questions,... I'm going to post here as comment to the question itself. If a new question pops up from your questoin or the answers to it, then you should do a new question (you can reference the old one in it but have to make sure ppl get it HOW it is different and why the answers dont answer it else it can get closed). If you see that answers/comments lead to details needing more clarification it is good to modify your question and post the additional/changed code there in order for teh answers to be adaptable to what is really needed to help you.

Comment: And last but not least if an answer answers your question you can sign it as being the answer that answers it. If there are multiple answers that fully answer your question or help you you can mark the most appropriate one as the final answer and +1 the others. (that is how most ppl handle things at least)

Comment: @Thomas I prefer posting new question about my problem.
Thank's

Answer (score 1):

You are missing one single check there then it should be ok: TiersLie.TiersEnfant.AdressePrincipale.Adresse.CodePostal != null. Thus:

```
dossiers = dossiers.Where(d => d != null && d.Demandeurs != null && 
           d.Demandeurs.Any(DossierTiers => DossierTiers != null &&
           DossierTiers.Tiers != null && DossierTiers.Tiers.TiersLiesEnfantsActifs != null &&
           DossierTiers.Tiers.TiersLiesEnfantsActifs.Any(TiersLie => TiersLie != null && TiersLie.TiersEnfant != null &&
           TiersLie.TiersEnfant.AdressePrincipale != null && TiersLie.TiersEnfant.AdressePrincipale.Adresse != null &&                
TiersLie.TiersEnfant.AdressePrincipale.Adresse.CodePostal != null &&           TiersLie.TiersEnfant.AdressePrincipale.Adresse.CodePostal.StartsWith("45")))).ToList();
```

As you have quite a lot of != null checks it would be good to reduce them to as few as necessary. The check for `d => d != null` as example SHOULDN'T be needed as when its null it shouldn't appear anyway as the element does not exist (Same holdes true for any `(a=> a != null` constructs. These elements shouldn't "appear" anyway as they don't exist.  In the answer I let it in still so that the code changes I made are just the minimal necessary for you to get your program to work.

EDIT: Taking the original command (mentioned in a comment) into account:

```
dossiers = dossiers.Where(d => 
           d.Defendeurs.Any(DossierTiers => DossierTiers.Tiers != null && 
           DossierTiers.Tiers.TiersLiesEnfantsActifs != null && 
           DossierTiers.Tiers.TiersLiesEnfantsActifs.Any(
                TiersLie => TiersLie.TiersEnfant != null && 
                TiersLie.TiersEnfant.AdressePrincipale != null && 
                TiersLie.TiersEnfant.AdressePrincipale.Adresse.CodePostal != null && 
                TiersLie.TiersEnfant.AdressePrincipale.Adresse.CodePostal.Contains("45"))))
          .ToLi‌​st();
```

Comment: Ok.The Original string is :  
 dossiers = dossiers.Where(d => d.Defendeurs.Any(DossierTiers => DossierTiers.Tiers.TiersLiesEnfantsActifs.Any(TiersLie => TiersLie.TiersEnfant.AdressePrincipale.Adresse.CodePostal.Contains("45")))).ToList();
and I got a nullReferenceException on TiersLie. So I must be check for null on the collection.

Comment: Ah we have some bad timing with making comments and editing them :) So the answer works for you? Can you also try out if the "edit" part works for you?

Comment: Ok, I take your code and it's work.
I must do the same thing now onto my function :

Answer (score 1):

I support the comment made that your model should be designed to avoid nulls - by initializing member collections to an empty collection rather than having them default to null. But if that's not an option, you should extract your null checking logic, which I'm guessing repeats itself, into a separate methods which can make the main clause more redable.

```
public bool IsValidDossier(Dossier d)
{
    return d != null 
           && d.Defendeurs.Any(DossierTiers => 
              DossierTiers.Tiers != null 
              && DossierTiers.Tiers.TiersLiesEnfantsActifs != null 
              && DossierTiers.Tiers.TiersLiesEnfantsActifs.Any(TiersLie =>       
                     TiersLie.TiersEnfant != null 
                     && TiersLie.TiersEnfant.AdressePrincipale != null 
                     && TiersLie.TiersEnfant.AdressePrincipale.Adresse.CodePostal != null;
}

public bool DossierMatchesPostalCode(Dossier d, string codePostal)
{
    return d.Defendeurs.Any(dt => dt.Tiers.TiersLiesEnfantsActifs.Any(tl => tl.TiersEnfant.AdressePriincipal.Adresse.CodePostal.Contains(codePostal);

}
```

And in your main code, you can reuse it:

```
var relevantDossiers = 
   dossier.Where(d => IsValidDossier(d) && DossierMatchesPostalCode(d, "45"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my function (base on somes functions found on the web) for generating the dynamic linq :

```
        public static Expression GetExpression(Expression parameter, object Operator, object value, params string[] properties)
        {
            Expression resultExpression = null;
            Expression childParameter, navigationPropertyPredicate;
            Type childType = null;

            if (properties.Count() > 1)
            {
                parameter = Expression.Property(parameter, properties[0]);
                var isCollection = typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(parameter.Type);
                if (isCollection)
                {
                    childType = parameter.Type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                    childParameter = Expression.Parameter(childType, childType.Name);
                }
                else
                {
                    childParameter = parameter;
                }
                var innerProperties = properties.Skip(1).ToArray();
                navigationPropertyPredicate = GetExpression(childParameter, Operator, value, innerProperties);
                if (isCollection)
                {
                    var anyMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().Single(m => m.Name == "Any" && m.GetParameters().Length == 2);
                    anyMethod = anyMethod.MakeGenericMethod(childType);
                    navigationPropertyPredicate = Expression.Call(anyMethod, parameter, navigationPropertyPredicate);
                    resultExpression = BuildLambda(parameter, navigationPropertyPredicate);
                }
                else
                {
                    resultExpression = navigationPropertyPredicate;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ConstantExpression right = null;
                var childProperty = parameter.Type.GetProperty(properties[0]);
                var left = Expression.Property(parameter, childProperty);
                right = (value != null) ? right = Expression.Constant(value, value.GetType()) : Expression.Constant(string.Empty);
                navigationPropertyPredicate = GetExpression(left, right, Operator);
                resultExpression = BuildLambda(parameter, navigationPropertyPredicate);
            }
            return resultExpression;
        }


       private static Expression GetExpression(MemberExpression left, ConstantExpression right, Object p)
        {
            MethodInfo c = null;
            if (p is OperatorUsedWithString)
            {
                switch ((OperatorUsedWithString)p)
                {
                    case OperatorUsedWithString.CommencePar:
                        c = typeof(string).GetMethod("StartsWith", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
                        return Expression.Call(left, c, right);
                    case OperatorUsedWithString.Contient:
                        c = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
                        return Expression.Call(left, c, right);
                    case OperatorUsedWithString.TerminePar:
                        c = typeof(string).GetMethod("EndsWith", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
                        return Expression.Call(left, c, right);
                    case OperatorUsedWithString.Egal:
                        c = typeof(string).GetMethod("Equals", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
                        return Expression.Call(left, c, right);

                }
            }
            if (p is OperatorUsedWithNumber)
            {
                switch ((OperatorUsedWithNumber)p)
                {
                    case OperatorUsedWithNumber.Egal:
                        return Expression.Equal(left, right);
                    case OperatorUsedWithNumber.Inferieur:
                        return Expression.LessThan(left, right);
                    case OperatorUsedWithNumber.InferieurEgal:
                        return Expression.LessThanOrEqual(left, right);
                    case OperatorUsedWithNumber.Superieur:
                        return Expression.GreaterThan(left, right);
                    case OperatorUsedWithNumber.SuperieurEgal:
                        return Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(left, right);



                }
            }
            if (p is OperatorUsedWithDateTime)
            {
                switch ((OperatorUsedWithDateTime)p)
                {
                    case OperatorUsedWithDateTime.PasPresent:
                        return Expression.Equal(left, Expression.Constant(null));
                    case OperatorUsedWithDateTime.Present:
                        return Expression.NotEqual(left, Expression.Constant(null));
                }


            }
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

and the BuildLambda :

```
       private static Expression BuildLambda(Expression parameter, Expression predicate)
        {
            var resultParameterVisitor = new ParameterVisitor();
            resultParameterVisitor.Visit(parameter);
            var resultParameter = resultParameterVisitor.Parameter;
            return Expression.Lambda(predicate, (ParameterExpression)resultParameter);
        }
```

I think , I just made change in this function but I try somes methods but none work.
So some helps are welcome.

Comment: uhm if it is a non working thing that you need help with you should either edit your question to accomodate it or post a new question, not post it as answer though. answers should be working things only that answer the question.

Comment: Ok,
Thank's I will post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `null` check in my `query` string

```
searchQ +=
    $"({objPropertiesName[i]} != null && " +
    $"{objPropertiesName[i]}.ToLower().Contains" +
    $"(\"{searchTerm}\")) || ";
```

And it is working like a charm.